# HyperV - vSwitch (Default Switch) Adapter Not Showing in Control Panel

Tags: windows-11, hyper-v, network-adapter

I have one VM running using the default switch.

[vm using default switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQlFT.png)

But I can not find the adapter exists on Control Panel > Network Connection.

Other people said it was hidden. By utilizing PowerShell, I found that it was really hidden.

[hidden default switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6c8kJ.png)

I want to configure the network via Control Panel so the hidden adapter is a problem for me.
How do I bring up the Default Switch adapter in the control panel?